# Create a cron to change "Out of Stock" status

Tags: magento2, cron, stock

I want to create a module or script which will run via cron once in a day to check the products whose qty is greater than 0 but with an "Out of Stock" status, and change it to "In Stock".

Can you please help me with the best practice to achieve this ?